# Neighbourhoods of a point with respect to the intersection of topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set and $\{\mathcal{T}_i \;;\;i\in I\}$ a family of topologies on $X$. Then $\mathcal{T}:=\bigcap_i\mathcal{T}_i$ is again a topology on $X$.

Do the neighbourhoods of a point $x\in X$ with respect to $\mathcal{T}$ admit a simple description in terms of the neighbourhoods with respect to the $\mathcal{T}_i$? Clearly we have
$$\mathcal{N}_{(X,\mathcal{T})}(x)\subseteq \bigcap_i \mathcal{N}_{(X,\mathcal{T}_i)}(x)\,,$$
but I don‘t see why the converse should hold.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $X$ and two $x\in A \subsetneq B\subsetneq X$. Take two topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ that are generate only by $A$ and $B$ respectively. The intersection of the two topologies is the trivial one $\{X,\emptyset\}$ so the only neighborhood of $x$ is $X$. But $\bigcap_i \mathcal{N}_{(X,\tau_i)}(x)$ is all the sets that have $B$ as a subset. So clearly the converse does not hold since $B$ is in the intersection but being different than $X$ it can't be a neighborhood of $x$ in the interseciton topology.